# Not the typical order by posts by date question

Tags: theme-development, wp-query

I am using WP_Query to get all posts from a custom post type. This works great for listing out all the posts. However, the post itself has a custom date field and I want to list all posts for a certain month under an `H2` tag that list the month without repeating the month. Currently I can loop through all posts but the `H2` with the month gets spit out every time. I don't want to make a month category either. The posts are for show dates. I want to list out all the dates for June but only have one `H2` with June in it and then all the posts under it.

Like this:

```
 1. June
    a. Show date
    b. Show date
    c. Show date
 2. July
    a. Show date 
    b. Show date
    c. Show date
```

and not this:

```
 1. June
    a. Show date
 1. June
    b. Show date
 1. June 
    c. Show date
 2. July
    a. Show date
 2. July
    b. Show date
 2. July
    c. Show date
```

Updated code:

```
$current_month = '';                    
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();?>  
<?php $date = strtotime( get_field('date') ); $month = date('F',$date); ?
<div class="row"><div class="span10">
   <h2>
     <?php if ($month != $current_month){
               $current_month = $month;
            echo $month; } ?>
```

Comment: Have u seen [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43299/wordpress-query-by-multiple-custom-fields-and-order-by-date?rq=1) question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you still have to order the posts by your date key, but as far as output, the general idea is to store the current month in a variable and check it against the date of each post, and only output it when it changes. A pseudo-code example:

```
$current_month = '';
while( have_posts() ){
    the_post();
    $this_month = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'your_date_key', true );
    if( $this_month != $current_month ){
        $current_month = $this_month;
        echo '<h2>' . $current_month . '</h2>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that at first but it only echo the last month

Comment: add the code you've tried to your question.

Comment: I figured out with Milo's help. I'll post the update code to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Time parameter in `wp_query` for getting the post filter on month

```
$today = getdate();
$query = new WP_Query( 'year=' . $today["year"] . '&monthnum=' . $today["mon"] . '&day=' . $today["mday"] );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters