# get wordpress post loop by meta box date

Tags: custom-field, loop, metabox

hello i just added date input by using metabox but i can't sort the loop in the front end page by latest metabox input date
i try this

```
$args = array(
'post_type'  => 'post',
'meta_key'       => 'meta_date', 
'meta_value_num' => ,
);
query_posts($guide); if(have_posts()){
 while(have_posts()) : the_post();
 echo get_the_title();
 endwhile;
}
```

but doesn't work for me ,
is there anyway to do that by using loop,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried passing in the $args variable to query_posts, rather than $guide?

```
query_posts($args);
```

Also, you should be looking to create the custom query using WP_Query class and not the query_posts. See this answer for more details (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755)

Try the below code:

```
$args = array('post_type'  => 'post', 'meta_key' => 'meta_date', 'meta_value_num' => , );

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if($my_query->have_posts() { 
    while($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
          echo get_the_title();
    endwhile;
}
```

Also, please see the following: [Order custom posts by a date metabox](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43277/order-custom-posts-by-a-date-metabox).

Comment: u just changed the var  !!

Comment: Hi Mouner. Sorry I misread part of your question. I thought you were having a problem passing the args to the query... I think this may be the answer to your question though: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43277/order-custom-posts-by-a-date-metabox

Comment: (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755) this answer is the best,thanks